# How do I concatenate an array on strings in ADF Data Flow to a simple string?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am building an Azure Data Factory. Inside a Data Flow I have an array of strings.

That array of strings I wish to merge into one single string.

ie. [ "value1", "value2" ] into "value1, value2"

Is that even possible, I can´t find any function helping me out here?

I wish there existed a join function or foreach but can't find any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dropLeft(toString(reduce(['value1','value2','value3','value4'], '', #acc + ', ' + #item, #result)), 2)
```

Results:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

Answer (score 0):

Does toString(myArray) do what you are looking for?

Comment: YES! And no. I did not realize toString actually works on arrays as well. So, this is part of my solution, followed by a couple of replaces as I need to clean it up. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **join** function which is present in **collection** functions in **Add dynamic content**.

[image]

**Syntax:**

```
join([<collection>], '<delimiter>')
```

**Example:**

```
join(variables('ARRAY_VARIABLE'), ',')
```

Refer this to learn more about the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#join).

Also, you can do it by using a **ForEach** loop activity to iterate over the array and use a **Set Variable** task with a **concat** expression function to create the comma separated string.

In case, you just have two elements in your array, then you can do like this.

```
@concat(variables('variable_name')[0].Code1, ',', variables('variable_name')[1].Code1)
```

Comment: The foreach does only exist in Pipeline, not in Data Flow. Neither is join available as part of the Aggregate schema modifier which I need to use in this case