# Regular expression in ADF

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-factory

How to split the string based on white spaces in DataFlow expression builder in ADF pipeline.
A string can have 1 or more white spaces.

```
Eg: 

I used split(name,’ ‘) : Thiswill split the word based on single space.Some times it can have more than 1 space. How to handle that?

Joe Smith(1 white space)
Joel  Smith(2 white space)
Joplin   Smith(3 white space)
```

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried and error if facing any?

Comment: @Pratik Lad - I used split(name,’ ‘) : Thiswill split the word based on single space.Some times it can have more than 1 space. How to handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my sample data with spaces.

[image]

```
column
Steve Smith C      S  K
Rakesh Govindula     Laddu
Chinna R     C      B
```

Use the below expression to get the words array without empty strings.

`filter(split(column,' '),#item!='')`

[image]

As there is no join function in dataflow expressions, to get the string of words with one space, use below expression from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089327) by **@Jarred Jobe**.

```
dropLeft(toString(reduce(filter(split(column,' '),#item!=''), '', #acc +  ' '  + #item, #result)), 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I notice a derivative of this problem from [other programming langauges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455750/replace-duplicate-spaces-with-a-single-space-in-t-sql).
If you want to remove multiple extra spaces then you can use 3 Replace() functions in a row to replace them with a single space.

If we set a parameter "newparam" to your example `"Joplin   Smith"`, we can use 3 replaces like so:

`@replace(replace(replace(pipeline().parameters.newparam, ' ', ' %'), '% ', ''), '%', '')`

Output after each replace:

```
 1 - "value": "Joplin % % %Smith"
 2 - "value": "Joplin %Smith"
 3 - "value": "Joplin Smith"
```

At this point you can wrap the command with the split() function and it will only intercept single spaces:

```
@split(replace(replace(replace(pipeline().parameters.newparam, ' ', ' %'), '% ', ''), '%', '')
, ' ')
```

Produces the array:

```
"value": [
        "Joplin",
        "Smith"
    ]
```