# How to fix error : ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, delimited

Facing an error while to load data from a csv file from fileshare to SQL table.

Error message:

> ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined, 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
> Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'file1.csv' with row number 5: found more columns than expected column count 17.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

Value of row number 5 is:

```
KPY,2524YT,PLOTTED,0,2524YT,PLOTTED,2524YT,PLOTTED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,A,2,2,231,ATON,ＩＮＣ.
```

Quote character is currently set as double quote (`""`), escape character is currently set as backslash (`\`)

I tried changing the escape character to double quote, but it didn't help

Comment: There *are* 18 columns in the row you've included in the question; none of the commas are escaped or quoted.  When I see ,INC. at the end, it makes me think  maybe it should have been "ATON, INC." -- regardless of which field, I think the next place to look would be whatever process encoded the csv.

Comment: @Gus Yes, the comma between ATON and INC is treating this as two different columns. It should be treated as just one column with the value "ATON, INC."

Comment: What setting changes to the ADF would help in resolving this error?

Comment: Are you using ADF to create file1.csv?

Comment: No. file1.csv is an extract from another data source shared in a file storage account mounted on another machine. Using ADF to consume the data from fil1.csv

Comment: I have the option of directly using the BLOB storage as well if that simplifies the solution. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file has extra `,` in your last column of that row. As your dataset delimiter also `,`, it is taking it as extra column which is causing the above error.

To overcome the above error, first your file should have different delimiter. Copy activity can't handle the row operations. So, use dataflow for that. But dataflow currently does not have support for File share as source.

So, first take a copy activity and copy the file from file share to temp storage like Data lake gen2 or blob storage. Use binary datasets as source and sink for this copy activity.

After that, take dataflow and source dataset should be this dataset with below configurations. Give Pipe(`|`) as column delimiter and uncheck the First row as header.

[image]

This takes all the columns as a single column with a column name like `_col0_`.

Next, take derived column in dataflow and use below expression on that column to replace the delimiter.

```
replace(replace({_col0_}, ',', '|'),'ATON|','ATON,')
```

[image]

In sink settings, give settings as one single file and give the filename.

[image]

This sink dataset should have below configurations.

[image]

This will generate the csv file like below.

[image]

Now, after dataflow activity, use another copy activity to copy the above file to your target.

For the source dataset of this copy activity, use another dataset with Pipe(`|`) delimiter settings like below.

[image]

**Result in SQL table:**

[image]

Comment: The sample row values I have given is from the input csv file. The actual file will have thousands of rows where not every row this may be the case where a column value may commas. In that case, how do I add expression. Is there any other simple way I can do it automatically considering the whole file may have some of the rows like this? I have the option of directly using the BLOB storage as well if that simplifies the solution. Please advise

Comment: Ok, You can do one workaround to replace those but for this you need to know the number of correct columns n before dataflow. In the derived column expression, first split the rows with `,` `split({_col0_},',')` this will give the array of size n for correct rows and size n+1 for the extra `,` rows. So use `iif()` on the length of the above array. If the length is equals to n, then just give `replace({_col0_},',','|')` in true expression. In the false expression, we should replace all `,`s except the last `,` of the row.

Comment: To do that use join with `|` of the [`slice()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#slice) of the above array from 1 to n. To join the array with `|`, use the expression like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089327/18836744). Then concat this result with last element of this array `split({_col0_},',')`. All this expression should be in false expression of `iif`.

Comment: So the total expression in derived column transformation would look like `iif(size(split({_col0_},',')==<n>),replace({_col0_},',','|'),concat(dropLeft(toString(reduce(slice(split({_col0_},','),1,<n>), '', #acc +  '|'  + #item, #result)), 0),split({_col0_},',')[<n>+1]))`. Please cross check this will small data before using it with your large data.